# What is the equivalent of cast for concepts?

Tags: c++, c++17, c++-concepts

Consider a `class A` satisfies two concepts `ConceptA` and `ConceptB`. Let a function `foo` is overloaded for the two concepts:

```
void foo(ConceptA& arg);
void foo(ConceptB& arg);
A a;
fun(concept_cast<ConceptA>(a));
```

*Note: This example uses the "Terse Notation" syntax proposed as part of [N3701](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3701.pdf), §5*

Is there something exist like `concept_cast` which allows users to select the overload?

Eg:
Lets say 
`ConceptA` says T has to have a member function `bar()`
`ConceptB` says T has to have a member function `baz()`
and `class A` has both `bar()` and `baz()` member function

Its clearly ambiguous, but is there a way to explicitly select like we have `static_cast` for normal overloads?

**Update**: Accepted answer is more than 2 years old. Any update in c++17?

Comment: Maybe that is an ambiguous overload to define in the first place? I'll be interested to hear the real answer.

Comment: Isn't this what `static_cast` does? Assuming `a` is derived from both `ConceptA` and `ConceptB`, that is.

Comment: @JonathanPotter `static_cast` into what?. Is it possible to `static_cast` into a `Concept`?

Comment: `foo(static_cast<ConceptA>(a));` when you want `foo(ConceptA&);`. Or have I misunderstood the question?

Comment: No. Iam talking about Concept feature of C++14

Comment: @balki it's not going to be in C++14. "Concepts-Lite" will be a separate ISO Technical Specification published around the same time as C++14. That's the plan anyway.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: One should cast it to reference instead of value, otherwise a new object will be constructed with slicing behavior. That is `static_cast<ConceptA&>(a)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If one of the concepts is a more constrained version of the other, (e.g. everything that satisfies `ConceptA` will also satisfy `ConceptB` but not vice versa), then the most-constrained overload that `A` satisfies will be chosen.

If neither concept is more constrained than the other, then the two are considered to be ambiguous overloads. Given how you phrased the question, I expect you already knew this.

Regarding `concept_cast`, I don't think there's anything like that in the current proposal. At least not as of the Bristol meeting (Apr '13). I don't expect this to have changed as the current focus seems to be on making sure the core of the concepts-lite/constraints proposal is workable and acceptable to the committee.

There'll probably be some demand for explicitly picking overloaded template functions like that, and maybe such a cast is the right thing, but I'm not so sure. Consider that such a cast would *only* be useful for overload disambiguation, where as `static_cast` is a more general feature. The result of the `concept_cast` would be same as the original value outside the context of overload resolution!

**Edit:** Looking at the latest proposal ([N3701](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3701.pdf)), there's no provision for explicitly specifying which template function to instantiate.

Answer (score 1):

Your claim that `static_cast` can be used to explicitly select a 'normal' overload is specious. It is possible to write the following in today's C++:

```
template<typename P, EnableIf<NullablePointer<P>>...>
void foo(P&);

template<typename It, EnableIf<Iterator<It>>...>
void foo(It&);
```

Assuming that `NullablePointer` and `Iterator` perform concept checking for the associated Standard concepts, then `int* q; foo(q);` has no hope of compiling because `int*` is both a model of `NullablePointer` and of `Iterator` (and neither concept subsumes the other). There's nothing obvious to `static_cast` to to help with that situation.

My example ([that you can test for yourself](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7f2da0d184d7069e)) is extremely relevant because this kind of code is what Concepts Lite attempts to formalize. The overload set you're presenting is equivalent to:

```
template<typename A>
    requires ConceptA<A>
void foo(A& arg);

template<typename B>
    requires ConceptB<B>
void foo(B& arg);
```

Notice the similarity between the `requires` clauses and the `EnableIf` 'clauses'.

Comment: There is, of course, nothing wrong with asking the question of 'will, or should, the language provide me with a way to disambiguate such ambiguous calls'.